# Assigning labels to triples

Tags: jena, ontology

I am currently trying to do stream reasoning using Jena, so I want to be able to reason over a certain set of triples that have occurred in a particular window of time, also taking into account some background static knowledge.

My problem is that I have an ontology that I read from several files, however I wish for the triples I obtain to have time stamps for when I receive them, which I thought I could just do by applying labels to the triples (I am just giving them all random time stamps for the moment as this is only a test).

While I didn't think that this would be problem, I am struggling at the initial step of just applying a label to an existing triple and selecting it. I cannot not seem to be able to access triples from the ontModel without having to transform it into a Graph, and while I could then create quads with the extra value being some literal for time, I can't find a way to then reason over this graph.

Any light that people can shed on this issue would help. I hope I am being clear.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what it is you'll do with the triple once you've got it, but I've added an answer about getting triples through statements from OntModels.   You mentioned stream reasoning, and there is existing work out there about complex event processing in RDF that might be relevant to whatever you're trying to do.  Have you taken a look at what any of those approaches to handle the timestamp/sequencing issues?

Comment: Additionally, if you're not already, you might want to have a look at The [reification section](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-mt/#ReifAndCont) of the RDF Semantics recommendation.  I don't expect that that's something you'll want to end up using, but it's good to know about, and might be relevant.

Comment: Yes I have been reading through various approaches to stream reasoning, they have been mainly research papers and just mention that they assign timestamps to triples, however I haven't found anything indicating a general approach. I will read into your your answer about FrontsTriple, I was not aware of it before. Also I should mention that I have been looking at C-SPARQL aswell, but it seems to have a few a small kink in it that annoys me, mainly that a query does not let me return a full triple with timestamp.

Comment: Ooo, I hadn't heard of C-SPARQL.  Many thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you're putting labels on your triples, but you can get [Statements](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Statement.html) from an OntModel, and Statement implements [FrontsTriple](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/FrontsTriple.html) through which you can access a corresponding [Triple](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/Triple.html).